# Should we migrate subjective question from StackOverflow ?

Tags: discussion, migration, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get a "Belongs on StackOverflow" as a closing reason?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-we-get-a-belongs-on-stackoverflow-as-a-closing-reason)

When the beta will be over, should the subjective question of StackOverflow be migrated here ?

Example question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364/what-is-the-single-most-effective-thing-you-did-to-improve-your-programming-skill
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the site survives beta then there will probably be a migration path set up.

In the meantime any currently *closed* question should be reposted here. Add a link to the question in comments (if you still can).

Comment: And maybe we even can set some mechanism (additional to regular closing or deletion) that will throw up some too stackoverflowish questions to stackoverflow:)

Comment: @Max - from comments that Jeff has made on Meta.StackOverflow migration will be set up between "related" sites so as not to overwhelm the close dialog. I would expect it to be enabled on both ends of the "relationship". We'll have to see what happens with Web Apps and Super User when the former comes out of beta.

Comment: yes, it would have been the best option.

Comment: Other sites already did migration of off-topic questions? How it did succeeded?

Comment: @bigown - Migration is something that needs to be coded by the Stack Overflow team. At present the beta sites can only migrate to their metas. Migration between sites is only enabled for Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User. When the new sites come out of beta they will be added to the close dialog if appropriate.