# Need clarification on what I can ask here

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about Windows Communication Foundation (WCF):

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127165/is-windows-communication-foundation-wcf-used-often

I don't have much work experience outside of my current job so I don't know what technologies are being used besides what I'm doing in my shop. Half the answers are helpful, the other half think the topic isn't constructive.

Ok that's fine I have NO issues with people thinking the topic is not constructive. To make it clear what I'm looking for, is there anywhere on stackoverflow I can post these type of questions?

I really like the format of the site and the people on here seem experience in the field

Comment: You would be better off finding a Windows forum to post this kind of question. If you *really* want to use SO for it, then maybe post it in one of the chatrooms, and check back every day or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no Stack Exchange site for this type of question. It is too localized, specifically it only applies to a specific moment in time. It's also dependent on industry and geographic location as to what technologies are used. There's also no objective criteria for "often".

I think there might already be questions about how to determine what technologies and languages are popular in given areas, and the answers to those questions point to different resources that you can use. I'd search around for those as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Some clarifications:

> Half the answers are helpful

Your questions (the one here and the one on StackOverflow) generated no answers, but [comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). It's good that some of the comments were helpful, but comments don't follow the same quality guidelines as answers. For example, there are no down votes on comments, so you can't really say if the community disagrees with a comment.

> the other half think the topic isn't constructive.

Unfortunately, regardless of how interesting your question may be, it doesn't have a single answer, and those kind of questions often lead to lengthy debates. We can't really safely measure a technology's popularity, your question is asking for opinions rather than experiences and facts. The pointers you got in the comments are valuable, but there's no objective way of judging them.

Adding to that, it's also too localized, as @ThomasOwens [explained](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2731/25936).

Make sure you read the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) and the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) blog post that is linked to the close notification and always keep in mind that "not constructive" is Stack Exchange lingo, it refers to how your question measures up to those guidelines. It's not a comment on the actual quality of your question.

And you can always try asking around in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Same crowd there, and your question is interesting enough to start a discussion (I hope). Of course the discussion will probably be more casual.

**As a sidenote**: Avoid [cross posting](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/what-is-the-current-policy-for-questions-that-are-duplicates-of-stack-overflow). If your question was closed on StackOverflow, chances are it will get closed here as well. Otherwise it would have been migrated instead of getting closed.

Comment: Yes I understand the situation and I have no issues with it. So basically I'm asking for advice on where to posts questions like this on stack but since Thomas said there's none that's fine. Just hoping someone can give me an alternated site I can ask these type of questions at.

Comment: Chat! Chat! Chat! :) That's your alternative, within the Stack Exchange network...