# Is recruiting appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I'm speaking mainly of [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/would-you-be-willing-to-donate-your-software-or-computer-talent-to-charity).  What do you think?

Comment: I edited the post:  The original is available here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/1020/revisions

Answer (score 11):

It's not a question of "opening the door" or it being a slippery slope: it's completely off topic for a Q&A site, even one more based on discussion like Programmers.SE.

It wouldn't be acceptable if someone was selling something in a question (e.g. "Would you buy X?"), and it's not acceptable merely because it's non-commercial. There are other venues for recruitment.

The question cited can—and should—be worded to remove the recruitment notice. It's ostensibly an on-topic question without it.

Answer (score 6):

My opinion matches Zneaks, in that it opens a bad door.

I wouldn't mind allowing MakerOfThings7's specific question, but we need to structure a rule on this such that we prevent both commercial recruitment efforts and getting flooded with well-meaning charity recruitment efforts.

As such, I'd vote we don't allow that sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like it. Accepting it would be opening the door to terrible things.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ would be a better place for such a thing. After all, donating work is the same as work.. you just don't get money for it. Perhaps some solicitation is just plain solicitation, but there are legitimate charities, and like every other industry around the world, they may need a place to seek this out.

Personally, I'd vote to not have it on programmers.SE, especially like the original edit. I would say the revised version is OK, since it is subjective - but now that's been asked anything further is a dupe.