# Is this question about users and their computer on-topic?

Tags: discussion

[How to deals with users that think their computer could think?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/how-to-deals-with-users-that-think-their-computer-could-think) does not answer to
"expert programmers who are interested in subjective discussions on software development"

Yet people are answering...

Is this question off-topic (it should probably then be asked on SU) or not?

I think it is, but why are other people missing it?

Comment: Wait, on here, non-subjective questions are off-topic? O_o

Comment: It depends in what way the question is objective, I guess there do exist objective questions that would still not fit on Stack Overflow and should be kept here. Ask a new meta question if you need more clarification...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Is it relevant to programmers and software development?** *I think so*: if you've ever had to deal with an end-user who has been having a *really hard time* with your software<sup>*</sup>, then you'll be immediately familiar with this attitude, as well as the importance of handling the situation without coming off as patronizing or unsympathetic.
2. **Is it an objectively-answerable programming question?** (i.e., does it belong on Stack Overflow) *No*. It's not a programming question, and the validity of any answer is a highly subjective matter.

Therefore, it is on-topic for this site.

<sup>*<sub>In many places, programmers are effectively the final support team, and end up dealing with users who are both important enough in some way to *get* that much support *and* are faced with some very challenging problems.</sub></sup>

Comment: Ah, seen like that, it totally makes sense... These two questions seem like a good guideline to base myself on in the feature.

Comment: In small companies, the programmers *are* the support team.