# How is this site different than Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and SO](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so)

This StackExchange Programmers Beta site seems very redundant to me. How is it intended to differ from StackOverflow?

Comment: Read the FAQ...

Comment: See also - http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/360/do-i-totally-not-understand-the-point-of-programmers-se

Comment: See also: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/237/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-are-off-topic and http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-migrate-subjective-question-from-stackoverflow

Comment: For starters, just look at the questions.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't read the FAQ/About page probably.

> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for
>   expert programmers who are interested
>   in subjective discussions on software
>   development.
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> - Software engineering
> - Developer testing
> - Developer tools and techniques
> - Practical algorithms and data structures
> - Design patterns
> - Architecture
> - **Development methodologies**
> - Quality assurance
> - **Software law**
> - Code golf & programming puzzles
> - **Freelancing and business concerns**

I think that most of this topics are not allowed on SO because they tend to reflect the personal opinions of the answer authors. SO is more for practical examples and objective facts. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize they changed the FAQ so much recently.

Comment: If **law** can be a topic of a *subjective* discussion ... What can't be? x) ...

Answer (score 3):

Programmers.SE is for **subjective discussions**

Stack Overflow is for **NON-subjective discussions**

funny thing is that there are a lot of question that end up on here that should go on SO.  Personally I think the title should be changed to make that more obvious.. but worlds not perfect.

Comment: Please, suggest which questions should be migrated to SO.

Comment: aw, now I have to look.  I know there is one I asked before I realized what this site was for.  I think it just ended up getting closed eventually opposed to migrated

Comment: Can I conclude that this is the best answer. Simply pointing out at faqs is kind of lame.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently referred here because I asked a subjective question on SO.  Apparently that is a big no-no.  That's what this site is for. (within reason)