# Can anyone define how the Programmers stack exchange is different from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have been lurking here for quite some time, and have seen questions that could probably be posted on stack overflow and get similar or even better answers. I am looking for a simple explanation as to what the primary difference is between the two exchanges, and what mindset I should have going into each one.

Comment: One's technical and specific, the other one's theoretical and generalized.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked many times before:

- Compare the [Help Center On-Topic page for Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to the [Help Center On-Topic page for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
- [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

  - [How is this site different than Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-is-this-site-different-than-stack-overflow?rq=1)
  - [What is the difference between Programmers and Stack overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/what-is-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow?rq=1)
  - [What is the difference between Stack Overflow and Programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/what-is-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers?rq=1)
- [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)
- [When do these questions belong on Programmers instead of Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/when-do-these-questions-belong-on-programmers-instead-of-stack-overflow?rq=1)

Comment: I would also add a reference to MSO faq question: [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254570/839601)