# What is exactly the difference between this site's topic and stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, websites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and SO](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so)

Sorry for the silly question, but looking at the question/answers in this beta i dont understand why this... exist.

So, like the title, what is the exact difference between the topics treated here and those in stackoverflow.com?

Comment: It depends on the results of the discussions on meta of this site, and what's currently in the FAQ. In general, SO deals with objective, can-be-answered programming questions, while this one deals with subjective, more programming related questions. Also, somebody will surely add (so to save him the trouble) that questions relating to any of the sites should be asked on meta sites of those sites.

Comment: This should be asked on the meta. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaNiel: Sorry to juggle your question around so much- this question has been asked here: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so