# Why Programmers when StackOverflow already exists?

Tags: programmers, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and SO](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so)

Why does this site exist when there is Stack overflow already?!!

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Why does this question is here when there is meta programmers?

Comment: Your kidding... have you seen the questions on this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is for more subjective questions than SO is for. SO is mostly about getting help, or a direct answer, for programming questions while this place has more argumentive answers.

Comment: So its for discussions and subjective questions? In that case a question like 'What is the best way to start on Ruby on rails' should go here or on SO? I ask this because I have seen these questions on SO when it should be here ideally.

Comment: My cent :- I really don't want to see these questions on stackoverflow. These type of question need their own space.

Answer (score 9):

So we can ask questions like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35887/why-programmers-when-stackoverflow-already-exists

Comment: Oh no an Overflow!!!