# Difference between programmers and stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and SO](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so)

Not sure what kind of questions should post in [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and others in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Anyone?

Comment: See also http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/948/why-programmers-when-stackoverflow-already-exists

Comment: Have you read the [respective](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?