# What is the difference between Programmers and Stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, programmers, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

Like the title says; What is the difference between Stackoverflow and this Q&A site?

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/

Answer (score 6):

I think of SO as being about "programming problems" and PSE as being about "problems *with* programming" -- i.e. a meta discussion about the process of programming.