# I wish programmers.stackexchange.com didn't exist

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

Programmers.stackexchange.com fractured the programming questions into two places. Users aren't sure where to post certain questions. Users are voting to close a question and the only evident reason for closing seems to be because they want it moved to programmers from SO. Then why isn't there an option to vote to move, or I am seeing it?

It seems StackExchange should be the one named Programmers, it's more logical, and SO is the overflow lot for other programming questions. (YES I KNOW SO came first.)

I never visit programmers SE and never thought about searching in it but now I can see there are good questions in it which I always thought SO is the place for them. So now I have to search both sites for certain questions like questions about frameworks, design.. and such. A thumb down for that.

I wish there was a tag called `[programmers]` on SO for questions which are programming related but are not a pure programming/coding question. This way all questions are in one site, abolish the confusion among users and use the tag to filter in or out as you wish.

Comment: This has been covered on meta.SO several thousand times

Comment: And i was about to vote to close as dup...shoot!

Comment: There is [an option to migrate from SO to Programmers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sNzoY.png). Note that migrating a question from Stack Overflow requires 4 votes out of 5 to be for the migration (or a moderator needs to pitch in with a binding vote).

Comment: @Michael Maybe so and this is NOT meta.SO.

Comment: It's NOT a dup. I am wishing there weren't two.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, or Firefox is screwing with me, but I could have sworn I saw "closed as exact duplicate" underneath this post.

Comment: @Tony What sort of support are you expecting when you come to a site and tell the users their site shouldn't exist?

Comment: @Anna I am not looking for support. I am expressing an opinion where I don't like to see several SE sites existing for what basically are very similar. I expressed the same opinion when SO announced the cooperation with doctype.com and we had to figure out where to put our css & html questions.

Comment: close by a single mod, how unexpected

Answer (score 2):

Dang, and here I was thinking that when I had a question about:

- Software engineering
- Developer testing
- Algorithm and data structure concepts
- Design patterns
- Architecture
- Development methodologies
- Quality assurance
- Software licensing
- Freelancing and business concerns

and that probably:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
- tend to have long, not short, answers.
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
- invite sharing experiences over opinions.
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
- are more than just mindless social fun.

I always seem to come here. I knew I was doing something wrong ...

Comment: I bet a ton of users do not know Programmers site exists and they are missing good answers.

Comment: I bet a ton of programmers don't know that [so] exists and are still going to forums. I bet a ton of developers don't know about git|hg, and are still using SVN or worse. I bet a ton of people driving cars have never had driving lessons. What's your point?

Comment: My point is SO is where most developers go to for answers. I personally know many developers who know about SO but never heard of Programmers. It doesn't click with developers that there would be more than one SE site for programming. It's basic logic. and your analogies make little sense. I am talking about the same entity splitting its own users.

Comment: No, you're expecting most users to know about the related SE sites. Most SO users have never even HEARD of the rest of the network. They want answers and to go on. The ones of us who _care_ are tasked with spreading that word.

Comment: Did you just repeat what I said!? My complaint is I don't want the split of sites because many users DO NOT KNOW about the different sites. I don't want to get into a discussion here. I expressed my opinion. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @tony the internet is so confusing. Thousands of sites, all different. How does anyone *find* anything?

Comment: I bet a ton of people would rather have a site where you can *talk* about things instead of trying to break everything down into black and white answers, which seems to be the entire concept of StackExchange - break everything down into "The answer of a is b" and discourage discussion and opinions.