# Difference between Programmers and StackOverFlow

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

What is the difference between "http://programmers.stackexchange.com" and StackOverFlow.

Comment: Check out the FAQ of both and you will see. It is clearly defined in there!

Comment: Now [P.SE Help Center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [SO Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @user40980 ment that FAQ became those 2...