# What the .... no, where (are) the FAQs?

Tags: support, faq-contents

I've found a bunch of FAQ links here on meta.p.SE, all pointing to [programmers.stackexchange.com/faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) etc, for example [this one over here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/difference-between-programmers-and-stackoverflow?rq=1), to name just one. Maybe it is just my browser, but I am always redirected to the about page once I try to follow that link. Well, that's a nice page too, there's no question about it, but it's not a FAQ.

So where the FAQ are the FAQs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FAQs got turned into the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) some time ago. The equivalent pages for the most part are [on topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [don't ask](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).