# Programmers vs Stack Overflow, why does this site exist?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

This site really does baffle me. I do not understand what question someone could ask here that he or she could not ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by reading these:

- [Stack Overflow On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) vs [Programmers On Topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)
- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

If you still don't understand where your question can go, you can either ask about it on a site's Meta (although you will have to be somewhat specific so that you can be directed to the right site), in a site's chat room (you have sufficient reputation to go ask), or you can choose the site you think is the most appropriate and if it's off-topic but still a good question for someplace else, have it migrated (don't cross-post questions, though - we'll make sure the question gets to where it can be answered).

---

Examples of questions that were originally asked on Stack Overflow, but migrated here because they were off-topic there and on-topic here:

- [Is allocating objects from a memory-pool a security anti-pattern?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238513/is-allocating-objects-from-a-memory-pool-a-security-anti-pattern)
- [Using subclasses for DataContracts used with JSON](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237692/using-subclasses-for-datacontracts-used-with-json)
- [DDD - Domain Driven Design, which development order should be applied?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235170/ddd-domain-driven-design-which-development-order-should-be-applied)
- [Decoupling Server and Client using REST API](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232032/decoupling-server-and-client-using-rest-api)
- [Is the Adapter the correct design pattern for this situation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231627/is-the-adapter-the-correct-design-pattern-for-this-situation)
- [Iteratively improve software architecture & quality in an agile process?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/230363/iteratively-improve-software-architecture-quality-in-an-agile-process)
- [Sequence Diagram. UML "Use Case Ends"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223834/sequence-diagram-uml-use-case-ends)
- [How can you add acknowledgement functionality to a Command pattern, given the response from receiver is gotten asynchronously on Server?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223878/how-can-you-add-acknowledgement-functionality-to-a-command-pattern-given-the-re)

Comment: I read that post. Did you read the question? Does a question exist that I can ask here but not on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes. Most questions here not closed would likely be migrated here if asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you show a question that was migrated? I've been asking algorithm / conceptual question on stack overflow for years.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I've added 8 examples to this post of questions that were migrated to Programmers from Stack Overflow. I think the help centers on the two sites make it very clear what is on-topic for each site. If a site could do something to make it more clear, please start a discussion on the appropriate Meta site.