# Add a question link to the tour

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

This question should be added to the tour of programmers.stackexchange.com IMHO.

Every programmer coming on the site tries to know what's the difference with stackoverflow, where to go on one or the other.

If not linking to the question, at least the reasoning should be shown somewhere. Right now, only when searching on meta can we find the reason.

Comment: The only sections of the tour that are editable by mods are the "Ask about" and "Don't ask about" lists. Perhaps we could mention Stack Overflow next to "implementation issues and coding tools" in the "Don't ask about" list, similarly to how we do in the help center: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @YannisRizos oh.. I didn't even see the help center had gone there.