# Will runnable stack-snippets ever be a feature for this site?

Tags: discussion

StackOverflow has had [runnable snippets for a number of years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). I notice the feature is absent from this site.

It's been noted that [having source code in your question is okay here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/173/325688), so will this feature ever be implemented?

Comment: Not sure if such a feature would not give people the very wrong impression that coding questions are on-topic on this site. Even if the number of such questions has gone down since the site name was changed, there are still too many ignorants out there who don't care to inform themselves about the site's focus and its distinction from Stackoverflow.

Comment: runnable snippets would only be a JavaScript thing, which would be available to a minute fraction of questions we receive. Most are language-agnostic, or assume Java, C#, or Python.

Comment: @amon: your comment is fine, but you may be astonished if you check the question count for tags C++, PHP, Javascript, and Python.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see the need for that here.

While code is OK most questions won't include it because they don't need it. It seems to be overkill to enable something that will only be used on a handful of questions.