# Lots of subjective questions here

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

It seems like half of this site should be community wiki. Also, what kind of questions are supposed to go here that don't already fit into StackOverflow or Webmasters? Webmasters is loosely defined as it is. This site only means to complicate it even more.

Comment: Also see: [Should we migrate subjective question from StackOverflow?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-migrate-subjective-question-from-stackoverflow), [Should we have a "not subjective enough" close reason?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/14/should-we-have-a-not-subjective-enough-close-reason), and [Why would anyone accept an answer?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-would-anyone-accept-an-answer)

Comment: Also: [What's the difference between Programmers and SO](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You know all those questions on Stack Overflow that get (or should get) closed as "subjective and argumentative", you know one's like: "what's your favourite programmer cartoon", "what language/framework should I learn next"?

Well this is the place to ask them without fear of them being closed (except perhaps as a duplicate).

## Important note

This question was posted and my answer written before the "constructive subjective" policy was introduced - [Six Subjective Guidelines](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice). So the example questions I quote should be regarded as theoretical questions only.

Answer (score 3):

For this site, I tend to think that Community Wiki should only be encouraged for collaborative editing...

If all questions that should be CW on a normal site be CW here then reputation would be nearly useless,
and I still tend to think that reputation should still be there to show the activity  and experience an user has.