# Can I ask a Subject Question about Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow, subjective

I know subjective questions are unacceptable on stackoverflow.com, but what if the question is directly about stackoverflow, for example:

- Have you noticed more [insert lanuage
  of you choice] questions on
  stackoverflow now that college
  started?
- Do you believe their are better
  technical questions asked on
  stackoverflow during the summer?
- Do you think those that program in a
  particular language ask better
  technical questions on stackoverflow?

Would subjective questions about stackoverflow be acceptable here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this site is for extended and subjective questions about *programming*, not Stack Overflow. If you want to talk about Stack Overflow, use [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).