# Ideas about a project and guidance on career enhancement aren't off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

What I understand from the FAQ is that any question concerning Ideas for a project and career enhancement doesn't seem appropriate for the site, no matter in what context or manner they are put up.

So, I kind of flag them as off-topic or not fulfilling any of the six guidelines. Am I going correct or should consider few things before flagging them because now and then I see these floating easily with moderators answering them.

Questions in this context which are still open : -

- [What would be a good first functional programming project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79608/what-would-be-a-good-first-functional-programming-project)
- [Get a job in C#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69056/get-a-job-in-c)

There are some other questions too like these

Comment: can you provide specific examples please

Comment: @JeffAtwood : I have listed the examples

Answer (score 3):

Based on your examples, those look closeable to me. They probably predate the /faq changes and got missed.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

> #### Can I ask career advice questions?
>
> No, unless your question is specifically about software development and requires the unique insights of a programmer. Most career advice questions [run the risk of being closed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster/590#590): try to make yours a good subjective question.
>
> Please make sure your question has the proper scope. If your question can also be applied to other jobs then it's not really something that uniquely applies to software development.

Comment: that's why I flagged these questions, but since the moderators haven't closed the question I was curious to know if my assumptions were wrong. These questions are still open.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - did you actually flag them or does "flagging" mean list them in the question?

Comment: I flagged them. After that, they were not closed so i listed them here in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Only one of those questions shows a flag from you.

That said, I closed a bunch of "what project should I choose" questions in the last week or so, and I agree that generally they are off-topic.

This was also brought up by Hugo in an answer [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/should-our-faq-contain-a-list-of-whats-off-topic-and-if-so-what-should-that-list/2292#2292). Since this keeps coming up, I'm going to update the FAQ to explicitly mention "suggest a project for me" kind of questions.

Comment: hmm.....dat will be good....One of them was edited by you, so i was concern if my flagging was correct.

Comment: Yeah, I just changed the tags last night. I debated closing it at the time, and with discussion here today, it's closed now.